# Symfony2 404 page load takes minutes

Tags: symfony

Recently changed servers for a domain. Running Symfony2 when you hit a 404 error page it literally takes at least 2 minutes to load. Other pages usually take less than 3 seconds. Any clue what might be causing this?

Comment: Have you checked the timing panel in the profiler? Might offer some insight.

Comment: I'm trying to set it up but I'm having a hard time finding good documentation other than what is in the Internals section of the documentation. I've done what is shown there. How do I now access the profiler? I can't turn on the toolbar since this is production.

Comment: I got this to work in the dev environment but It would be nice to know how to do this in production. Looks like I need to know the request ID to be able to actually access the profiler.

Comment: I see now that I should be able to grab the x-debug-token header value, but when I try to access the profiler using that value it tells me it can't find a request matching the token. Getting closer!